# Why doesn't this code give any output, why does the execution not terminate?

Tags: c, windows, unix

Whenever I run this code in codeblocks it compiles without any errors and warnings but when I execute it, it doesn't show any output nor does it terminate itself unlike other codes I've ran.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main ()
{
    int i = 1;
    while (i<=10);

    {
        printf("%d \n",i);
        i = i + 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Enable all compiler warnings.  A good well enabled compilare will warn like "warning: this 'while' clause does not guard... [-Wmisleading-indentation]     while (i<=10);" and "statement, but the latter is misleadingly indented as if it were guarded by the 'while'".  This saves you time.

Comment: Compiler do give warning but why doesn't compiler give any warning or error in braces of while after semicolon?

Comment: Priyank Dave Enable all warnings or use a better compiler.  What did you use to enable all warnings?  `-Wall` is insufficient with gcc.

Comment: voting to close because the question is due to a **typo**

Answer (score 4):

You've created an infinite loop due to a typo:

```
while (i<=10);
```

Remove the semicolon.